# Arima time series

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to build a arima time series model for demand prediction...
my data is on weekly level from 2014 and 2015 all weeks.  If I also use 2016 first 10 weeks data and then try to predict the for remaining week on wards. Will it be correct. How will arima model know that the seasonality is for 52 weeks .

Comment: How will ARIMA know about seasonality? Well, either you specify a seasonal ARIMA (SARIMA) and explicitly tell the seasonality is 52, or you may try a model with 52nd lag (*not* all lags until the 52nd, but a few plus the 52nd).

Comment: 'Will it be correct' is a difficult question to answer. Are you trying to ask if the model will be accurate?

Comment: thnks guys...i got the answer...i just need to mention the frequency as 52..got little confused... 
I am working on demand prediction for headphones category for my company. I am building the model for the same using past 2 years weekly data. I am using Arima for the same. Anyone here who have worked on similar kind of problem..can sugggest me something else..